# positioning of tables in print media view

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tables in the print media view created is not in the preferred format as expected.

Upon viewing how the page should be printed. The tables appear in the second page instead of the first page. I'm assuming it's a problem in the page break. I've tried numerous solutions from the net, but none seem to work.

Here is my media print code:

```
@media print {
   table td:last-child {display:none}
   table th:last-child {display:none}
   table td:last-child {display:none}
   table th:6th-child {display:none}
}
```

As of now, i still don't know the solution.

Here are some images to makes things a little clearer

This table that seems to be in the second page:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEYA9.png)

Should be printed here in the first page showed here:
[first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMh0b.png)

I need a solution to move the tables from the second page to the first page.

added here is the html code of the table:

```
          <table data-toggle="table" id="table-style" data-row-style="rowStyle">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th data-field="date"  data-sortable="true">Date</th>
                                                    <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Order No.</th>
                                                    <th data-field="agent"  data-sortable="true">Agent</th>
                                                    <th data-field="name"  data-sortable="true">Customer</th>
                                                    <th data-field="status"  data-sortable="true">Status</th>
                                                    <th id = "view">View</th>
                                                    <th id = "send">Send</th>
                                                    <th id = "send">Cancel</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                            @foreach($newOrdersQ as $order)
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><?= $order->date;?></td>
                                                        <td><?= $order->orderID;?></td>
                                                        <td><?= $order->agent;?></td>
                                                        <td><?= $order->customerCompany;?></td>
                                                        <td><?= $order->status;?></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <form id='viewButton' action='/specificView'>
                                                                <input class="btn btn-default" type="hidden" id='viewData' name="viewData" value='<?= $order->orderID;?>'>
                                                                <input class="btn btn-default" id='viewBtn' name="submit" type="submit" value="View">
                                                            </form>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <form id='toTBDid<?= $order->orderID;?>'>
                                                                <input type="hidden" id='sendData' name="sendData" value='<?= $order->orderID;?>'>
                                                                <input class="btn btn-default" id='viewBtn' name="submit_" type="button" value="Send" onclick='toTBDS(<?= $order->orderID;?>)'>
                                                            </form>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <form id='cancelOrderNO<?= $order->orderID;?>'>
                                                                <input type="hidden" id='sendData' name="sendData" value='<?= $order->orderID;?>'>
                                                                <input class="btn btn-default" id='viewBtn' name="submit_" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick='toTBDC(<?= $order->orderID;?>)'>
                                                            </form>
                                                         </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
```

Comment: Do you have a snippet of the page? Maybe the table is too big to fit in that box.

Comment: Could there be a solution wherein i could resize the table? @Rachel S

Comment: @PocholoDelenelaMendoza could you please share your html, css codes in a snippet please. We can work something out that way.

Comment: I have added the html code of the whole table. Is there still a way we can work this out? @Inuka